# Futures somehow slower then agents?

Tags: clojure

The following code does essentially just let you execute something like (function (range n)) in parallel.

```
(experiment-with-agents 10000 10 #(filter prime? %))
```

This for example finds the prime numbers between 0 and 10000 with 10 agents.

```
(experiment-with-futures 10000 10 #(filter prime? %))
```

Same just with futures.

Now the problem is that the solution with futures doesn't run faster with more futures. Example:

```
; Futures
(time (experiment-with-futures 10000 1 #(filter prime? %)))
"Elapsed time: 33417.524634 msecs"

(time (experiment-with-futures 10000 10 #(filter prime? %)))
"Elapsed time: 33891.495702 msecs"

; Agents
(time (experiment-with-agents 10000 1 #(filter prime? %)))
"Elapsed time: 33048.80492 msecs"

(time (experiment-with-agents 10000 10 #(filter prime? %)))
"Elapsed time: 9211.864133 msecs"
```

Why? Did I do something wrong (probably, new to Clojure and just playing around with stuff^^)? Because I thought that futures are actually prefered in that scenario.

Source:

```
(defn setup-agents
  [coll-size num-agents]
  (let [step (/ coll-size num-agents)
        parts (partition step (range coll-size))
        agents (for [_ (range num-agents)] (agent []) )
        vect (map #(into [] [%1 %2]) agents parts)]
    (vec vect)))

(defn start-agents
  [coll f]
  (for [[agent part] coll] (send agent into (f part))))

(defn results
  [agents]
  (apply await agents)
  (vec (flatten (map deref agents))))

(defn experiment-with-agents
  [coll-size num-agents f]
  (-> (setup-agents coll-size num-agents)
      (start-agents f)
      (results)))

(defn experiment-with-futures
  [coll-size num-futures f]
  (let [step (/ coll-size num-futures)
        parts (partition step (range coll-size))
        futures (for [index (range num-futures)] (future (f (nth parts index))))]
    (vec (flatten (map deref futures)))))
```

Comment: An aside, `(apply concat ...)` is almost always better than `(flatten ...)` and `(flatten (map ...))` can (and should) usually be replaced with `(mapcat ...)`

Comment: `(map #(into [] [%1 %2]) agents parts)` is also equivalent to `(map vector agents parts)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting tripped up by the fact that `for` produces a lazy sequence inside of `experiment-with-futures`. In particular, this piece of code:

```
(for [index (range num-futures)] (future (f (nth parts index))))
```

does not immediately create all of the futures; it returns a lazy sequence that will not create the futures until the contents of the sequence are realized. The code that realizes the lazy sequence is:

```
(vec (flatten (map deref futures)))
```

Here, `map` returns a lazy sequence of the dereferenced future results, backed by the lazy sequence of futures. As `vec` consumes results from the sequence produced by `map`, each new future is not submitted for processing until the previous one completes.

To get parallel processing, you need to not create the futures lazily. Try wrapping the `for` loop where you create the futures inside a `doall`.

The reason you're seeing an improvement with agents is the call to `(apply await agents)` immediately before you gather the agent results. Your `start-agents` function also returns a lazy sequence and does not actually dispatch the agent actions. An implementation detail of `apply` is that it completely realizes small sequences (under 20 items or so) passed to it. A side effect of passing `agents` to `apply` is that the sequence is realized and all agent actions are dispatched before it is handed off to `await`.